# How to asynchronously download an array of URLs as strings

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

My goal is to download an array of URLs (for example, 25 URLs) as strings, and report when the URLs have all finished downloading.

At the moment, I am able to successfully download from 1 webpage, as configured below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    self.downloadWebpage(url: url!)
}

func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _  response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data, response, error)
        if error != nil {
            print (error.debugDescription)
        }
    }.resume()
}

func downloadWebpage(url: URL) {
    getDataFromUrl(url: url) { (data, response, error)  in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        print("Download Finished")
        print (data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
            if let returnData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print (returnData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While I realize I could easily package my URLs inside an array, my difficulty is about getting the process to report that when *all* of the URLs from the array are downloaded (or, have error'ed out). Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick way**

*NSNotifications*

You set up a notification to fire when your downloads are done, then listen for that notification elsewhere in the application.

This article explains how;
https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/pass-data-with-nsnotification-in-swift-3-73743723c84b

**Proper way**

*Competition handlers*

https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/